# Assinging to a variable

Tags: python, class, variables

```
class main_window:

   def __init__(self, question):
      self.question = question

   def question_func(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.question)

q1 = main_window('In general, my problem is related to:')

main_window.question_func(q1)
```

How do i assign **main_window.question_func(q1)** to a variable which i can call ?

Comment: `question_func` returns a string, what do you intend to "call" here?

Comment: Is object oriented approach necessary for this? Functional programming seems to be the way to go.

Comment: your q1 is an instance of the class, may be you want to pass a string not a instance of main_window itself. Assuming you were to pass a string you could do something like this call_back = main_window.question_func, the pass the arg to it something like this call_back(q1)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
class main_window:

   def __init__(self, question):
      self.question = question

   def question_func(self):
      return '{}'.format(self.question)

q1 = main_window('In general, my problem is related to:')
variable = q1.question_func()
print(variable)
```

Output:

```
In general, my problem is related to:
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant thanks, can you explain the logic behind it? i cant understand why it worked

Comment: You create a `main_window` object `q1` and you assign some text to its attribute `question`. Then you invoke the function `question_func` on `q1` and assign the result (which happens to be the value of `question`) to `variable`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're doing "main_window.question_func(q1)". Perhaps you want to create a static/class method??

I think you may be triying to do something like this:

```
class main_window:

   def __init__(self, question):
      self.question = question

   def question_func(self):
      def function_toBe_called():
           return '{}'.format(self.question)

      # question_func returns a function that 
      # returns a string, not a string
      return function_toBe_called
```

And then you cand do:

```
q1 = main_window('In general, my problem is related to:')

variable_youCan_Call = main_window.question_func()
variable_youCan_Call()
```